# Switch or move circular background from one element to another on click

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to animate color from one to another list whenever I click any list icon see in below image

[image: select weekdays]

```css
.days-cal li {
  color: #d5d1e6;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding-top: 06px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: 0.5s linear;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}
.days-cal li.active {
  background: #4B916C;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 0;
  padding-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="expand-view inven-l">
  <div class="item">
    <ul class="days-cal">
      <li ng-class="{'active':weekOf==1}" ng-click="weekSelect(1)">Sun</li>
      <li ng-class="{'active':weekOf==2}" ng-click="weekSelect(2)">Mon</li>
      <li ng-class="{'active':weekOf==3}" ng-click="weekSelect(3)">Tue</li>
      <li ng-class="{'active':weekOf==4}" ng-click="weekSelect(4)">Wed</li>
      <li ng-class="{'active':weekOf==5}" ng-click="weekSelect(5)">Thu</li>
      <li ng-class="{'active':weekOf==6}" ng-click="weekSelect(6)">Fri</li>
      <li ng-class="{'active':weekOf==7}" ng-click="weekSelect(7)">Sat</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to create the structure/layout or atleast a circle? Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: yes i have added a code  of list of days and css

Comment: can you share also your function to see how you use ng-class. so we see how you mange this and eventually have a clue for the selector usable ? As is it may look like you also need the angular part ...

Comment: @Harry okay, looked to me it was part of it :)

Answer (score 5):

**Using Dummy Element and Transform:**

One way to achieve this would be to use a dummy element inside the `ul.days-cal` which creates the circle and then translate it (using CSS transform) based on the index of the element that is clicked.

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  var translateX = ($(this).index()) * 46; /* width + 2 * margin */
  $('ul.days-cal .circle').css('transform', 'translateX(' + translateX + 'px)');
});
```

```css
.days-cal li {
  color: #d5d1e6;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  text-align: center;
}
.days-cal {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.days-cal li.circle {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  background: #4B916C;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expand-view inven-l">
  <div class="item">
    <ul class="days-cal">
      <li>Sun</li>
      <li>Mon</li>
      <li>Tue</li>
      <li>Wed</li>
      <li>Thu</li>
      <li>Fri</li>
      <li>Sat</li>
      <li class='circle'></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Using Radial Gradients:** (no extra element required)

Another way to achieve this without using any extra dummy elements would be to use radial gradients as background image for the `ul.days-cal` and then adjust the `background-position` of the gradient depending on the index of the element that is clicked.

The disadvantage of using radial gradient is that it won't work in IE9-.

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  var translateX = ($(this).index()) * 46; /* width + 2 * margin */
  $('ul.days-cal').css('background-position', translateX + 'px 0px');
});
```

```css
.days-cal li {
  color: #d5d1e6;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  text-align: center;
}
.days-cal {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  height: 42px;
  list-style: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(36px 36px at 24px 24px, #4B916C 48.5%, transparent 51%);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expand-view inven-l">
  <div class="item">
    <ul class="days-cal">
      <li>Sun</li>
      <li>Mon</li>
      <li>Tue</li>
      <li>Wed</li>
      <li>Thu</li>
      <li>Fri</li>
      <li>Sat</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to do it with angular

Comment: I have no idea of AngularJS as I've never used it @Mohammadshaban. My suggestion would be for you to accept this answer (if it helped) and ask a separate question for AngularJS integration because that wasn't a part of your original question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet to show how CSS could do this. I use here tabindex, but i also could use form element **to mimic whatever the missing function does with ng-class when you click on your items** (could not guess it but waiting for you to update question so i can update answser :) ).

The CSS part to mind is the `nth-child(x)` and the selector `~` so you can update coordonates of a pseudo produced by  the last item.

```js
/// WELL your function is missing, so i do not link snippet to any library  ///
// IN the  CSS part, replace occurance of :focus by .active  //
```

```css
.item {
  font-size:16px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  margin:1em;
}
.days-cal li {
  color: #d5d1e6;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:36px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 19px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
/* replace occurance of :focus by .active  */
.days-cal li:nth-child(7):focus:before {
  left:345px;  
}
.days-cal li:nth-child(6):focus ~ li:last-of-type:before {
  left:295px;  
}
.days-cal li:nth-child(5):focus ~ li:last-of-type:before {
  left:245px;  
}
.days-cal li:nth-child(4):focus ~ li:last-of-type:before {
  left:195px;  
}

.days-cal li:nth-child(3):focus ~ li:last-of-type:before {
  left:145px;  
}
.days-cal li:nth-child(2):focus ~ li:last-of-type:before {
  left:95px;  
}
.days-cal li:nth-child(1):focus ~ li:last-of-type:before {
  left:45px;  
}
li:last-of-type:before {
  content:'';
  height:36px;
  width:36px;
  display:inline-block;
  background: #4B916C;
  position:absolute;
  left:-50px;
  transition:left 0.5s;
  z-index:-1;
  border-radius:50%;
}
li:focus {
  animation:dripple 0.5s 
}
@keyframes dripple {
  0 , 50%{
    box-shadow:0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5) , inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3) , inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 0 0 0  rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
  20% {
    box-shadow:0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 0 3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), inset 0 0 2px 9px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 0 2px 11px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }
}

body {
  background:#352B58;
}
```

```html
<div class="expand-view inven-l">
  <div class="item">
    <!-- DISCLAIMER/ tabindex is used to show that CSS can achieve this, but we need to relay on your js function to fully adapt to your code -->
    <ul class="days-cal" ng-controller="MainController as vc">
      <li  tabindex="0" ng-class="{'active':weekOf==1}" ng-click="weekSelect(1)">Sun</li>
      <li  tabindex="0" ng-class="{'active':weekOf==2}" ng-click="weekSelect(2)">Mon</li>
      <li  tabindex="0" ng-class="{'active':weekOf==3}" ng-click="weekSelect(3)">Tue</li>
      <li  tabindex="0" ng-class="{'active':weekOf==4}" ng-click="weekSelect(4)">Wed</li>
      <li  tabindex="0" ng-class="{'active':weekOf==5}" ng-click="weekSelect(5)">Thu</li>
      <li  tabindex="0" ng-class="{'active':weekOf==6}" ng-click="weekSelect(6)">Fri</li>
      <li  tabindex="0" ng-class="{'active':weekOf==7}" ng-click="weekSelect(7)">Sat</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen to play with or fork](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wGQjzZ)

Comment: The answer by the way is excellent. Getting it done with just CSS is awesome :)